# When to use MongoOperations and MongoTemplate?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I went through many links before raising this question. What's the difference between MongoTemplate and MongoOperations?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html)

> Interface that specifies a basic set of MongoDB operations.
>   Implemented by MongoTemplate. Not often used but a useful option for
>   extensibility and testability (**as it can be easily mocked, stubbed, or
>   be the target of a JDK proxy**)

I think the following statement is self explanatory.